# How do people who recently bought a Macbook Pro get the free upgrade to Lion?

Tags: upgrade, macos

When I bought my Macbook Pro I was told that when Lion came out I could get the upgrade for free.  How do I go about doing this?  I've searched the Apple.com website extensively and can't find information on this.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I think new versions of OSX **are** going to be Dirt Cheap from now on. I don't think Snow Leopard was inexpensive only to get users "over the hump". I think it's a "give away the razor, to sell the blades" situation all over again.

Comment: Sorry, but any idea where those eligible can get it free please?

Comment: google it, i think it was called the lion 'up to date' program

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Lion up to date program is public](http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/). It currently says the deadline to ask for a free copy is August 19, 2011 and macs purchased on or after June 6, 2011 are eligible.

Otherwise, **Mac OS X 10.7 Lion will cost you $29.99, and is available on the Mac App Store ([link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-lion/id444303913?mt=12&ls=1)).** You can also go to an Apple store to download it (if you have a slow connection), and Apple will be making a version on a USB thumb drive available for $70. (More info [here](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/07/20Mac-OS-X-Lion-Available-Today-From-the-Mac-App-Store.html).)

Comment: I´d rather say *no one knows yet*, but since it´s a fair guess: +1

Comment: @Asmus This is based on prices for past OS updates.

Comment: I paid CAD$29 for the single seat, 10.5 -> 10.6 upgrade DVD at [the Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/ca/product/MC573Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDAzOA&mco=MTc1MTEzNjY) when it was released, not $60-$80. Wife got a CAD$7 upgrade to iLife '11 for her month-old MBPro back in November. Basically covered the costs of shipping the media.

Comment: @Nathan Sure, and it is - as I said - a fair guess. But it *is* pure speculation at this moment, isn´t it?

Comment: @Ian C: The Snow Leopard upgrade was much less than others because it was a small upgrade in terms of features. Other upgrades have historically cost more.

Comment: @Nathan - when you wrote, "*based on prices for past OS updates*"—can you give an example of an OS X version that cost more than $30 and less than $129? Also: Apple doesn't do update pricing, per se; it's always been free to go from 10.n to 10.n.xx, and everything else is the same full price for everyone.

Comment: I would be interested in what sources were used to establish these price guesses. Please link in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

To answer the more general question as to what Apples policy is for software updates for Macs purchased in the run up to a major release: Historically, Apples 'Up-to-Date' programs for free or heavily discounted upgrades have been offered to those who have purchased a new Mac within 2 weeks (i.e. the duration of the standard return policy) of a major OS update. This is primarily done to prevent those users from simply returning and rebuying the machine on launch day. Additionally, at times, Apple has announced up to date availiability for everyone who has purchased a machine between *the announcement of a specific release date* and that release date. This is fairly uncommon however, and if they do so for Lion, you'll hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

The program initially allowed for people that bought macs on or after June 6, 2011 had a filing deadline of August 19, 2011. A follow-on program for macs purchased after July 21, 2011 has a 30 day after purchase claim window.

Both programs were documented at http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/ . It looks like there was an August 2011 deadline to ask for a refund / free copy of Lion.

---

Historically, Apple honors upgrade / price matching requests for the time of the new purchase return period (2 weeks in the US) and has occasionally offered fulfillment plans to lengthen that window to encourage sales once a firm release date is announced. If you buy a new mac the day of a new software release (and until the new software gets included in the build at the factory) the box has a "drop in kit" installed with the new software free of charge.

Of course you could always ask for a free upgrade, but since the window is 2 weeks, you might not convince someone to give you a free upgrade if the purchase was several months before the eventual release. If you have a good relationship with your seller - shoot them a mail or stop by the store to let them know to contact you if they can help with pricing when it releases.

Also, the price for 10.6 was $29 for 10.5 owners so depending on the release price details, that may affect how far back Apple chooses to offer gratis copies of the new Lion software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [this](http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/) for more information.